# Making fields in user profile rich text editor

Tags: php, wysiwyg, social-networking

For user profile son my site I have some fields like: Career experience where the user can detail out his career. I want to add some in-line rich editor features like bullet points, bold text, etc but without all the icons. So users need to add the html like  to make it bold. At the same time i want to restrict other html so no one includes tables or other bad html into the form.

So I assume to do this i need a wysiwyg field instead of a regular form field? And how to make the field like that? I am using codeignitor php for my framework, are there any open source adds on to this or do i need to handcode the field?

Comment: You could just have [Google'd for it](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+rich+text+editor). ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are packages which do this sort of thing for you. I'm familiar with [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), which is pretty good... easy to integrate and simple, familiar UI.

Comment: Those are for large text fields like for email entry, question/answer entry, etc. I need something without the icons just a field that will accept html input on small fields like a 200 char field. So if users have a small list of items they can bullet point those instead of using a comma.

Comment: @Jean - TinyMCE is actually very flexible, and you can choose whether to display all those formatting bars or not. I'd look at the customization options of TinyMCE and other similar packages before giving up on them.